# Python - Importing Excel dates converts to number

Tags: python, xlrd

I'm trying to learn to the use the xlrd package in Python to read Excel files, and I have made a sample file which contains a list of chronological dates and in the second column the day of the week it corresponds to.

The problem is that when I read in the data it displays it as a number.  How can I get the date to display the way it is supposed to?

```
[u'Date', u'Day']
[41162.0, u'Monday']
[41163.0, u'Tuesday']
[41164.0, u'Wednesday']
[41165.0, u'Thursday']
[41166.0, u'Friday']
```

Comment: If I remember right, excel's internal date format is number of days since its epoch. the decimal place is used for hours/minutes.

Comment: The function [xlrd.xldate_as_tuple-function](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.xldate_as_tuple-function) should be what you are looking for.

Comment: bah pedro your comment beat my answer :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you want

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook("somewb.xls")
my_date_tuple = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(xls_timestamp_number,wb.datemode)
```

which then returns a date tuple that is much easier to work with :)

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime(1899,12,30) + datetime.timedelta(days=int(41162.0))
datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 10, 0, 0)
```